# React Native Button Icon how to be position right?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons

```
import React from 'react';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

<Button
 style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}  
 title="Download"
 onPress={handleDownload}
 disabled={isButtonDisabled}
 icon={
 <AntDesign name="download" size={20} color="white" style={{alignSelf: "flex-end"}} />
}
        
/>
```

I can tried Icon position right but it didn't work. Can anybody help me how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.